# trouble finishing a laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

i am trying to find the solution to this second order differential equation below.

$y''(t) + 4 \cdot y(t) = 0.5,$ with $y(0) = 2, y'(0) = -1$

i have made some progress on this.

$Y(s)$ is given by:

$L(y''(t)) + 4 \cdot L(y(t)) = 0.5 \cdot L(1)$

by the rules of laplace transforms:

$s^2 \cdot Y(s) - s \cdot y(0) - y'(0) + 4 \cdot Y(s) = s^2 * Y(s) - 2s + 1 + 4 \cdot Y(s)$

$s^2 \cdot Y(s) - 2s +  + 4 \cdot Y(s) = \frac{1}{2s}$

$Y(s) \cdot (s^2 + 4) = \frac{1}{2s} + 2s - 1$

$Y(s) = \frac{1}{2s \cdot (s^2 + 4)} + \frac{2s}{s^2 + 4} - \frac{1}{s^2 + 4}$

this is where i got stuck. i don't know what to do with the $\frac{1}{2s \cdot (s^2 + 4)}$ term. i was thinking of using partial fractions, but i am not sure how to separate the original fraction.

any advice on how to proceed? thank you in advance.

Comment: You are exactly right. Use partial fractions to represent your first fraction in the transform

Answer (score 1):

You can separate using partial fractions. You just need to look for fractions of the form

$$\frac{1}{2s(s^2+4)}= \frac{A}{s}+\frac{Bs+C}{s^2+4}$$

By clearing denominators and equating coefficients of $s$ we see that $A= 1/8$, $B = -1/8$ and $C = 0$

Comment: thank you @podiki. why $\frac{A}{s} + \frac{Bs + C}{s^2 + 4}$ though? i don't see where that comes from. this partial fraction is a little more complex than what i'm used to seeing.

Comment: In general the numerator has to be a polynomial of $1$ less degree than the denominator. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Factors_of_the_denominator) entry has a length but solid discussion of this.